# Snapchat QR code from Snapchat username php

Tags: php, qr-code, snapchat

I would like to generate the Snapchat snaptag(QR code) that is assigned to each user with their username. i have looked around for a while now and found nothing at all.

I would really appreciate some help!
Thanks a lot,
Robert

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is the API that snapchat itself uses:

https://feelinsonice.appspot.com/web/deeplink/snapcode?username=USERNAME&size=400&type=PNG

`feelinsonice-hrd.appspot.com` works too.

No documentation, of course, but you can fool around with it.

Answer (score 0):

It comes standard on the new update, just open up the app and crook down, those dots around the snapchat logo is your QR code.

Answer (score 0):

I've just written a [blog post on how to acquire your SnapChat QR code / SnapCode.](http://joel-murphy.com/snapchat-qr-codes-snapcodes-is-there-an-api/)

If you don't want to read the entire post, then I'll answer your question here. Yes this is possible, but not through an API (just yet?)

SnapChat have recently released a new website for downloading your own SnapCode, but it isn't currently possible to download anyones own personal SnapCode using an API or anything.